# Interactuar con Lista Java

Tags: java, lista

La lista `listdescripcionS` me trae un array con datos string. No sé cómo obtener esos datos en el `for` y que por ciclo del for asigne el correspondiente dato.

```
DynamicDTO dynamicDto = new DynamicDTO();
List<String> listdescripcionS = osirisDelegate.obtenerdescripcionSeccionales(dynamicDto);
for (String  descripcion : listdescripcionS) {
    /* acá irían las instrucciones para imprimir cada dado en una variable*/
}
```

Comment: ¿Buscas algo como `System.out.println` o qué es lo que necesitas hacer?

Comment: Hola Luigi, si necesito guardarlo en una variable e imprimirlo en un system.out.println

Comment: ¿En qué variable debe guardarse y cómo? ¿Tienes algún método set en particular que debas utilizar?

Comment: Bueno realmente si, tengo un set para asignarlo a un metodo lo declaro  dentro del for de esta forma      Tm_Plan_Capacita_Cab planCapacCabObjSave = new Tm_Plan_Capacita_Cab();  y de ahi comienzo a setearle los campos, este en particular es un campo que le debo asignar a ese metodo seria algo como /planCapacCabObjSave.setId_seccional(descripcion); pero realmente no sé como hacerlo, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salvo que tengas alguna otra cosa que hacer, basta con imprimir la variable `descripcion`:

```java
for(String descripcion : listadescripcionS) {
    // Opción 1:
    System.out.println(descripcion);
    // Opción 2:
    System.out.println(String.format("Descripción:\t%s", descripcion));
}
```

El "estilo" `for(T t : collection)` quiere decir, literalmente: *"Para cada objeto de tipo `T` dentro de la colección dada"* (es el estilo *"for-each"*). En el caso del ejemplo que planteas en tu pregunta, lo que estás diciendo es: *"Para cada `descripcion` en la lista `listadescripcionS` haz lo que está entre llaves"*.

Ahora bien, si necesitas hacer alguna otra cosa con los valores guardados en la lista, puedes pasar la variable `descripcion` al método que necesites ejecutar:

```java
for(String descripcion : listadescripcionS) {
    miMetodo(descripcion);
    /*
    // Si tu método regresa algo y después tienes 
    // que hacer otra cosa con ese algo, puedes
    // escribir algo como esto:

    T unObjeto = miMetodo(descripcion);

    // donde T es algún tipo (o clase).
    // Después podrás hacer lo que sea necesario con `unObjeto`.
    */
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

En tu for la variable de tipo String descripcion, a la que siguen los dos puntos, guarda el valor de la posición de la lista en cada iteración.

Esta variable la puedes imprimir, asignar a otra, etc...

Espero haberte entendido correctamente

Comment: Con lo que me dices ya puedo seguir con el metodo, muchas gracias :)